# Setting up family sharing without credit card

Tags: icloud, catalina, apple-id, family-sharing

I'm trying to create an account for my child who is 8. I've learned that family sharing is the way to go, however it requires adding a credit card to the payment method. Now I do have a credit card but this method is not available for India.

So what would be the best way to create an account through which my child can log in? I've already created a standard user account but I'd want to monitor what's happening in that account and if possible, also control it without actually logging into it.

I've looked at screen time but I am worried if screen time settings could be changed from within the standard user's account? I'd like to use screen time from my own administrator account but I want the settings to be transparent to my child.